# Bulk insert operation into Parent and Child table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, asp.net-core, bulkinsert

For our current project(.Net Core), we require a migration of old data where the data is in an excel sheet in plain format. We need to import the data and then create those data into our database. There are multiple tables involved in this migration. Suppose the tables are:

```
table Parent(
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
  Name varchar(120),
  value varchar(150)
)

table Child1(
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
  childvalue1 varchar(120),
  childvalue2 varchar(150),
  P_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER foreign_key # has an index
)

table Child2(
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY,
  child2value1 varchar(200),
  P_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER foreign_key # has an index
)
```

The relationship is: **Parent has 1-to-many Child1,Child2**.

The parent table has a reference to table A.

The format the data are present in excel sheet is:
`Name - value - childvalue1 - childvalue2 - child2value1`

There are thousands of rows in this format.

What I want to do is:

- copy the excel data into a table
- create a stored procedure to insert into the parent and child tables

My concern here is:

- How can I map the parent id to the children while uploading the data row by row?
- while inserting the entries Id also has to be generated and the id is of type GUID

Comment: Assuming you've worked out how to import it, based on the answer below, your next challenge is to link records. Firstly I recommend an `INT` over a `GUID` unless you have a good reason. The question is: are the values for `name`, `childvalue1`, `childvalue2`  `child2value1` unique - can you use these values to uniquely recognise nodes?.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid the property name in parent table is unique, the rest of the values are unique on row level

Comment: To automatically assign a GUID your three column definitions should be `Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newsequentialid() NOT NULL`

Comment: Are you able to load your 5 attributes into different columns or are they in one big string seperated by `-`?

Comment: i have updated the primary key generation to automatically generate the id's. when you are asking me about loading the attributes into different columns, did you mean while uploading the data from excel sheet to the temporary table or loading the data from temp table to the stored procedure?

Comment: I'm trying to work out whether I also need to provide that part of the solution - splitting columns. I'll assume I don't

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `bulk insert` from an `Excel file` to a `database` if you want to have a performant application follow this approach.

1. First of all, create a `temp table` corresponding to your Excel file columns and one more column with the name of `InsertionKey`.
2. Insert all your input data from excel with the same InsertionKey (generate a new GUID) and all your Excel rows will have the same key. (Use Entity Framework `BulkInsertAsync` or `SqlBulkCopy` for bulk insert. You also can check my [GitHub](https://github.com/MajeQafouri/EFBulkInsertBenchmark) repo for benchmarking BulkInsert in .Net)
3. After data is inserted, send the `GUID` as a parameter to a stored procedure

Now, you can easily process all your inserted data by fetching them from the temp table with the key.

**Example**:

Your excel file columns:

```
Item1   Red      25
Item2   Black    32
Item3   Orange   44
```

Generate a new Guid before bulk insert

```
var insertionKey = Guid.NewGuid();
```

Now bulk insert into DB:

```
Item1   Red      25    insertionKey
Item2   Black    32    insertionKey
Item3   Orange   44    insertionKey
```

Now call the stored procedure with the `Insertionkey`

```
YourStoredProcedure(Insertionkey)
```

Inside the stored procedure:

```
select *  
into #temp 
from temptable 
where insertionKey = insertionKeyParameter
```

Here you can read inserted rows and after that process them as you want.

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. I will have a go with your solution and will get back to you.

Comment: Good. Let me know, if you had any question

Comment: it worked for me. Just finished this part of the project. Although it slightly tweaked your solution. Thanks @Majid

Comment: I'm very happy to hear that.

Answer (score 2):

Here a sample script that gives a concept of how you can do it. It relies on the values being unique, that is, a given name/value only has one meaning

First you need to load your excel data into the Stage table.

Then you can use T-SQL to farm these values out to three table. By joining back on values you can retrieve the parent id's

Note there's no looping here, it's a set based solution.

```
DECLARE @Parent TABLE (
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newsequentialid() NOT NULL,
  Name varchar(120),
  value varchar(150)
)

DECLARE @Child1 TABLE(
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newsequentialid() NOT NULL,
  childvalue1 varchar(120),
  childvalue2 varchar(150),
  P_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)

DECLARE @Child2 TABLE (
  Id UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT newsequentialid() NOT NULL,
  child2value1 varchar(200),
  P_ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
)


-- This is the stage table that excel data is loaded into
DECLARE @Stage  TABLE (
    COL1 VARCHAR(100),
    COL2 VARCHAR(100),
    COL3 VARCHAR(100),
    COL4 VARCHAR(100),
    COL5 VARCHAR(100)
    )

-- Load sample data
INSERT INTO @Stage(COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5)
VALUES 
('Name1','value1','childvalue1','childvalue2','child2value1'),
('Name1','value1','childvalue3','childvalue4','child4value1'),
('Name1','value1','childvalue3','childvalue4','child4value2'),
('Name1','value1','childvalue3','childvalue4','child4value3'),
('Name2','value2','childvalue8','childvalue5','child5value1'),
('Name2','value2','childvalue8','childvalue6','child6value1'),
('Name2','value2','childvalue8','childvalue6','child6value2')

-- Save top level, generating id's
INSERT INTO @Parent(Name,Value)
SELECT DISTINCT COL1,COL2 FROM @Stage

-- save children, looking up id's based on actual values
INSERT INTO @Child1(P_ID,childvalue1,childvalue2)
SELECT DISTINCT P.Id, S.COL3,S.COL4 
FROM @Stage S
INNER JOIN @Parent P
-- relies on these values being unique
ON S.COL1 = P.Name
AND S.COL2 = P.value

-- Check results    
SELECT * FROM @Parent
SELECT * FROM @Child1
```

Comment: thank you @Nick. for providing me a way of doing the first part of the solution